# glmnet doesn't work in R caret package: all the RMSE metric values are missing:

Tags: r, r-caret, glmnet

Find problems when using glmnet in caret package. The original glmnet works for the same input data. Random Forest works for the same data in caret.

**Example code**

```
library(caret)
library(glmnet)
data(iris)
head(iris)
x = iris[,1:3]
y = iris[, 4]


fit = glmnet(as.matrix(x), y)
print(fit)
#plot(fit, xvar = "lambda", label = TRUE)

rfFit <- caret::train( x=x, y=y, method = 'rf', verbose = TRUE)
rfFit

glmFit <- caret::train( x=x, y=y, method = 'glmnet', verbose = TRUE)
#glmFit

sessionInfo()
```

**Output**:

```
fit = glmnet(as.matrix(x), y)
str(fit, max.level = 1)
List of 12
 $ a0       : Named num [1:75] 1.199 1.061 0.934 0.819 0.714 ...
  ..- attr(*, "names")= chr [1:75] "s0" "s1" "s2" "s3" ...
 $ beta     :Formal class 'dgCMatrix' [package "Matrix"] with 6 slots
 $ df       : int [1:75] 0 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 1 ...
 $ dim      : int [1:2] 3 75
 $ lambda   : num [1:75] 0.731 0.666 0.607 0.553 0.504 ...
 $ dev.ratio: num [1:75] 0 0.157 0.288 0.397 0.487 ...
 $ nulldev  : num 86.6
 $ npasses  : int 493
 $ jerr     : int 0
 $ offset   : logi FALSE
 $ call     : language glmnet(x = as.matrix(x), y = y)
 $ nobs     : int 150
 - attr(*, "class")= chr [1:2] "elnet" "glmnet"
plot(fit, xvar = "lambda", label = TRUE)





rfFit <- caret::train( x=x, y=y, method = 'rf', verbose = TRUE)
note: only 2 unique complexity parameters in default grid. Truncating the grid to 2 .

rfFit
Random Forest 

150 samples
  3 predictors

No pre-processing
Resampling: Bootstrapped (25 reps) 
Summary of sample sizes: 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, 150, ... 
Resampling results across tuning parameters:

  mtry  RMSE       Rsquared   RMSE SD     Rsquared SD
  2     0.2042819  0.9299771  0.02026926  0.01435902 
  3     0.2073273  0.9285442  0.02054641  0.01473437 

RMSE was used to select the optimal model using  the smallest value.
The final value used for the model was mtry = 2. 






glmFit <- caret::train( x=x, y=y, method = 'glmnet', verbose = TRUE)
Something is wrong; all the RMSE metric values are missing:
      RMSE        Rsquared  
 Min.   : NA   Min.   : NA  
 1st Qu.: NA   1st Qu.: NA  
 Median : NA   Median : NA  
 Mean   :NaN   Mean   :NaN  
 3rd Qu.: NA   3rd Qu.: NA  
 Max.   : NA   Max.   : NA  
 NA's   :9     NA's   :9    
Error in train.default(x = x, y = y, method = "glmnet", verbose = TRUE) : 
  Stopping
In addition: There were 50 or more warnings (use warnings() to see the first 50)






sessionInfo()
R version 3.1.3 (2015-03-09)
Platform: x86_64-unknown-linux-gnu (64-bit)

locale:
 [1] LC_CTYPE=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NUMERIC=C              
 [3] LC_TIME=en_US.UTF-8        LC_COLLATE=en_US.UTF-8    
 [5] LC_MONETARY=en_US.UTF-8    LC_MESSAGES=en_US.UTF-8   
 [7] LC_PAPER=en_US.UTF-8       LC_NAME=C                 
 [9] LC_ADDRESS=C               LC_TELEPHONE=C            
[11] LC_MEASUREMENT=en_US.UTF-8 LC_IDENTIFICATION=C       

attached base packages:
[1] stats4    parallel  stats     graphics  grDevices utils     datasets 
[8] methods   base     

other attached packages:
 [1] glmnet_2.0-2         Matrix_1.1-5         elasticnet_1.1      
 [4] lars_1.2             caret_6.0-64         lattice_0.20-30     
 [7] plyr_1.8.3           optparse_1.3.2       GenomicRanges_1.18.4
[10] GenomeInfoDb_1.2.5   IRanges_2.0.1        S4Vectors_0.4.0     
[13] BiocGenerics_0.12.1  stringr_1.0.0        doMC_1.3.4          
[16] iterators_1.0.8      foreach_1.4.3        mclust_5.0.2        
[19] randomForest_4.6-10  ggplot2_1.0.1       

loaded via a namespace (and not attached):
 [1] car_2.0-25         codetools_0.2-10   colorspace_1.2-6   compiler_3.1.3    
 [5] digest_0.6.8       getopt_1.20.0      grid_3.1.3         gtable_0.1.2      
 [9] lme4_1.1-10        magrittr_1.5       MASS_7.3-39        MatrixModels_0.4-1
[13] mgcv_1.8-4         minqa_1.2.4        munsell_0.4.2      nlme_3.1-120      
[17] nloptr_1.0.4       nnet_7.3-9         pbkrtest_0.4-2     proto_0.3-10      
[21] quantreg_5.19      Rcpp_0.12.0        reshape2_1.4.1     scales_0.3.0      
[25] SparseM_1.7        splines_3.1.3      stringi_0.5-5      tools_3.1.3       
[29] XVector_0.6.0
```

=====================================

Any suggestion is appreciated. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Find the solution at one thread:
[Caret error using GBM, but not without caret](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/29802216/caret-error-using-gbm-but-not-without-caret).

Removing VERBOSE option fixes the problem